# Sugarcrm CE Fatal error: sugar_file_put_contents_atomic() in wamp

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am running Sugarcrm CE under wamp on a windows 7 machine and I keep getting the following error. It just happens randomly and if I reload the page it seems to work. But this error is very annoying and I never used to get it under this development environment. I know if this was linux it would be a permissions issue but permissions look fine in windows to me. I have developer mode switched on and have deleted the cache folder but it still happens. Does anybody know how to prevent this?

```
Fatal error: sugar_file_put_contents_atomic() : fatal rename failure 'E:\wamp     \www\sugargantt-project\cache\modules\Employees\tem177F.tmp' -> 'cache/modules/Employees/Employeevardefs.php' in E:\wamp\www\sugargantt-project\include\utils\sugar_file_utils.php on line 187
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the 'cache' directory but found it was owned by 'root' so I resolved it by correcting ownership from the sugarcrm directory:

```
chown -R apache:apache .
```

Where 'apache' is your web server user.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error and fixed it by editing the realpath_cache_size setting from the default of 16k to 32k in my php.ini.

```
realpath_cache_size = 32k
```

**EDIT**: Although, the above solution helped, this issue returned in my local development environment (I am running on Windows 7). I ended up resolving it by closing my PHP IDE, PhpED by NuSphere, and deleting the localhost debugging cookie in my browser that this IDE sets named "DBGSESSID". I re-ran my local sugarCRM instance again without PhpED and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this issue and resolved it by performing following steps

The root folder of sugar must have a folder named 'cache' in which it creates the cache files.If the folder is missing then create one.

Increase the Memory usage and script execution time in php.ini file, i had set these to Memoray: 256, Script execution time to 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Visit `http://localhost/?phpinfo=1` and see if WinCache or APC are enabled. They're both caching mechanisms for PHP on Windows environments, and I've had similar issues with such things in Sugar where temporary files aren't able to be deleted and rebuilt correctly.

If one or the other are enabled, you'll want to modify your active php.ini file or otherwise disable the PHP module from the WAMP menu.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a cache directory in root directory of sugarcrm and check permission on it make it 777 and try hard reload it after this